# Magento 2: Add block above page-header

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, blocks, header

I tried to add a simple div into my Magento 2 theme.
I've added this code to

> /app/code/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
      <container name="topline" as="topline" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="topline" before="page.header">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.line" template="Magento_Theme::topline.phtml" />
      </container>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

And I added this file with some test content:

> /app/code/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/topline.phtml

Of course, I've tried other answers here in StackExchange, but nothing worked. I read that when there's no content, the dom even does not appear - is that correct? But main question: what's wrong with my code? Btw, mage cache cleared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your **default.xml** to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.line" template="Magento_Theme::topline.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you want to add your block to top header change `<referenceContainer/>` to

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
```

Now flush cache and try.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I found a small but epc mistake in my "config": the directory was not templates but template... omg!

Comment: to add the block to the top of the header: add the before argument: <block ... before="-">

Comment: Yes, you can also use `before` and `after` to repositioning blocks.

Comment: I'm using <move element="my_block" destination="header.container" before="-" /> to put a block at the very top position.

Comment: No displaying in site ??

Comment: Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::topline.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'top.line'